# Como carregar os dados de um arquivo XML em um campo input HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, regex

Estou tentando carregar um XML fazendo upload salvando em um objeto e mostrando na tela.
Consegui fazer mostrando em uma Div

Mas não estou conseguindo mostrando em Inputs.

Segue o processo e o código:

Escolho o Arquivo e clico em Upload

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O Resultado é este:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Gostaria que ao invés de mostrar desta forma mostrasse dentro de Inputs dessa forma:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo o Código **HTML**

```
 <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" />
    <hr />
    <form>
            CNPJ:
  <input type="text" name="firstname"><br><br>
  Nome:
  <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
  Emit:
  <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
  IE:
  <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
  CRT:
  <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>

    <div id="dvTable">
    </div>
```

**Codigo JS**

```
      $(function () {
        $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xml)$/;
            if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(e.target.result);
                        var nfe = $(xmlDoc).find("emit");

                        //Create a HTML Table element.
                        var table = $("<table />");
                        table[0].border = "1";

                        //Add the header row.
                        var row = $(table[0].insertRow(-1));
                        nfe.eq(0).children().each(function () {
                            var headerCell = $("<th />");
                            headerCell.html(this.nodeName);
                            row.append(headerCell);
                        });

                        //Add the data rows.
                        $(nfe).each(function () {
                            row = $(table[0].insertRow(-1));
                            $(this).children().each(function () {
                                var cell = $("<td />");
                                cell.html($(this).text());
                                row.append(cell);
                            });
                        });

                        var dvTable = $("#dvTable");
                        dvTable.html("");
                        dvTable.append(table);
                    }
                    reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
                } else {
                    alert("Este browser não suporta HTML5.");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Por favor faça Upload de um arquivo XML valido.");
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No laço `$(this).children().each` coloque um seletor dos `input text` pegando o índice dos elementos do XML e adicionando os valores sequencialmente aos campos:

```
//Add the data rows.
$(nfe).each(function () {
    row = $(table[0].insertRow(-1));
    $(this).children().each(function (e) { // <-- adicione 'e' como parâmetro para pegar os índices do laço
        var cell = $("<td />");
        cell.html($(this).text());
        row.append(cell);
       $($("input:text")[e]).val($(this).text()); // <-- insere valores nos campos
    });
});
```

Comment: Tentei usar desta forma que voce informou mas não deu certo

Comment: @ShaolinFantastic Pode mostrar uma amostra da estrutura do XML? O exemplo acima é esquemático e funciona. Mas depende muito da estrutura do seu XML para pegar os valores.

Comment: Eu tentei fazer dessa forma tambem para trazer direto no input que eu gostaria mas não funcionou... $($('#CNPJ')[e]).val($(this).val(CNPJ));

Comment: @ShaolinFantastic To vendo que se trata de um XML de alguma coisa fiscal e os dados devem ser sigilosos, claro. Se quiser enviar o XML com as informações para o meu email eu posso verificar. Depois eu apago tudo.